# Most Significant Byte Calculation

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a larger cipher problem, and I am running into an issue I don't quite understand when taking the Most Significant Byte (not bit).

To turn an int into a byte I am using:

```
def binary(i):
    if i == 0:
        return "0"
    s = ''
    while i:
        if i & 1 == 1:
            s = "1" + s
        else:
            s = "0" + s
        i >>= 1
    return s
```

I am pretty sure the above is correct, it works with my test numbers. To then extract the Most Significant Byte I am using:

```
def msb(i):
    a = binary(i)
    b = a[0:7]
    c = int(b,2)
    return c
```

However, this seems to return a number half what I would expect. Am I wrong in thinking you can get the most significant byte by just taking the first 8 bits, or am I missing something else silly?

Comment: Is the goal to get the top aligned byte, or the highest eight bits set? Makes a big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code only gets the **seven** leading bits, not 8:

```
def msb(i):
    a = binary(i)
    b = a[0:7]   # gets first SEVEN characters of string a
    c = int(b,2)
    return c
```

Change it to `a[0:8]` to extract 8 leading characters/bits rather than 7.

Comment: Damn, been a while since i used python, i forgot about array indexing...thanks you very much, that now works perfectly!

Comment: good answer :) this is the actual problem with his code i think ... mine provides a different way to solve

Comment: @user2851268, you should check out the `bitstring` module which will handle all the gory details of manipulating bit strings and converting them to integers for you. http://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/

Answer (score 4):

There are much easier ways to do this. For example, if you want the top eight bits (ignoring byte alignment), you can do:

```
def msb(val):
    return val >> (val.bit_length() - 8)
```

For the most significant aligned byte, in Python 3 you can do:

```
def msb(val):
    return val.to_bytes((val.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big')[0]
```

In Py2, you'd have to convert to a hex string and back to match the `to_bytes` approach.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a much better way of doing things, I think i need to do more study on bit operations!

Answer (score 0):

a byte is `0xFF` you can get the most signifigant byte(leftmost) by doing

```
i & (0xFF<<(n_bytes(i)-1))
```

I always get most significant and least significant confused if you want the rightmost byte its easier even

```
i & 0xFF
```

i think thats right at least ... im not sure if it will be guaranteed to return the number of bytes or not ...

based on your example i think the second code is what you want

you could also do something like

```
 s = struct.pack("i",i)
 ord(s[0])  # leftmost
 ord(s[-1]) # rightmost
```

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` is returning a number that is essentially useless to this particular case. It's the size of the Python allocations (which includes object structure), which is only loosely tied to the magnitude of `i`.

Comment: bah i dont know how to get the number of bytes ... i gues numbits / 8

Answer (score 0):

If you want aligned bytes, this should work at least from Python 2.5 onwards:

```
def msb(val):
    return 0 if val == 0 else val >> (((val.bit_length() - 1) >> 3) << 3)
```

Or, if you prefer it more readable:

```
def msb(val)
    if val == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return val >> (((val.bit_length() - 1) / 8) * 8)
```